# Redux Returning Default Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am using React Native along with Redux for an app I am building. I am also using two npm modules, react-native-simple-store, and redux promise. I will explain the use of each as I continue explaining my problem.

I have a basic action creator that fires in a componentWillMount method. The purpose of this action creator is to retrieve an array of data from the user's device. I use react-native-simple-store to do this, as it always returns the data you request as a promise. Here is my action creator:

```
import store from 'react-native-simple-store'
export const GET_ALARMS = 'get_alarms'

export const getAlarms = () => {
  // this variable will hold the promise
  let alarms = store.get('alarms')

  return {
    type: GET_ALARMS,
    payload: alarms
  }
}
```

In my reducer, I was hoping to receive the array I was asking for in my action creator. However, it does not work, and I end up with an empty array returned every time. Here is my reducer:

```
import GET_ALARMS from '../actions/getAlarms'

export default (state = [], action) => {
  console.log(action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_ALARMS':
      return [...state, action.payload]
  }

  return state
}
```

What's interesting, is when I console.log the action coming into the reducer, I see this in the console:

```
Object { type: "get_alarms", payload: Array(3) }
   payload: Array(3)
      0: Object
      1: Object
      2: Object
   type: "get_alarms"
```

This is the data I want, it is just an array with 3 objects inside of it. It's there, but I am missing something minute.

Any help on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes in your reducer

1. You have imported the ACtion Constant wrongly since it was not a default export, you need to use `{}`
2. In the Swtich case use this imported variable without quotes.

Your code

```
import {GET_ALARMS} from '../actions/getAlarms'

export default (state = [], action) => {
  console.log(action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALARMS:
      return [...state, action.payload]
  }

 return state
}
```

Comment: Happy to help Daniel :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your reducer, your action should be in capital letter :

`export const GET_ALARMS = 'GET_ALARMS'`.

Your switch case is case sensitive. That's why you never enter into the case.

Comment: Hey Antoine, thanks for the reply, but this wasn't actually the solution. Check the accepted answer to see what really happened.